# How to return a dataframe with the last non-NaN values in each column for each month?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
               A     B     C     D
2020-11-18  64.0  74.0  34.0  57.0
2020-11-20   NaN  71.0   NaN  58.0
2020-11-23   NaN  11.0   NaN   NaN
2020-11-25  69.0   NaN   NaN   0.0
2020-11-27   NaN  37.0  19.0   NaN
2020-11-29  63.0   NaN   NaN  85.0
2020-12-03   NaN  73.0   NaN  49.0
2020-12-10   NaN   NaN  32.0   NaN
2020-12-22  52.0  90.0  33.0  24.0
2020-12-23   NaN  96.0   NaN   NaN
2020-12-28  78.0   NaN   NaN  68.0
2020-12-29  17.0  70.0   NaN  16.0
2021-01-03  51.0  43.0   NaN  66.0
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe that contains the last non-NaN values for each month in each column:

```
               A     B     C     D
2020-11     63.0  37.0  19.0  85.0
2020-12     17.0  70.0  33.0  16.0
```

I tried grouping by month and applying a lambda that returns the in-group maximum index like so:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.index.max())]
```

which yields:

```
               A     B     C     D
2020-11-29  63.0   NaN   NaN  85.0
2020-12-29  17.0  70.0   NaN  16.0
```

This returns the values that appear on the last day in each month but not the last non-NaN value. In case the value for the last day in a particular month is a NaN, I will have a NaN appearing here. Instead, I'd only like to have NaN values present if there are absolutely no values for that particular month in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).last()
print (df)
            A     B     C     D
2020-11  63.0  37.0  19.0  85.0
2020-12  17.0  70.0  33.0  16.0
2021-01  51.0  43.0   NaN  66.0
```